# codeigniter error datadase and array to string conversion

Tags: database, codeigniter, activerecord

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
Line Number: 428
```

A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
SELECT * FROM (`user`) WHERE `id` = Array
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 331
```

my model

```
function update_customer($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query;  
    }
```

my controller

```
function save_order()
{
     $customer = array(
            'name'      => $this->input->post('full_name'),
            'email'     => $this->input->post('email'),
            'address'   => $this->input->post('address'),
            'phone'     => $this->input->post('telp')
            );      
     $this->cart_model->update_customer($customer);
}
```

I do not know where my mistake, please corrected thanks

Comment: You need to use db->update when updating http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to update in `update_customer()` function instead selecting the rows.

```
function update_customer($data = array())
    {
        $this->db->update('user',$data); //updates data in user table 
    }
```